# How to open image file using pdftron

Tags: image, pdftron

I want to load an image file using the [pdftron webviewer api](https://www.pdftron.com/webviewer/demo/documentation.html).

For pdf files it's working fine but I want to load image files and add annotations to them.

In the [user guide](https://www.pdftron.com/webviewer/demo/doc/WebViewer_User_Guide.pdf) there is no information regarding working with images.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, WebViewer can do this out of the box.

There are a number of image formats supported. Here is the breakdown.

**PNG, JPEG**

Simply pass the image URL to WebViewer initialDoc constructor parameter, or to WebViewer.[loadDocument](https://www.pdftron.com/webviewer/demo/doc/symbols/PDFTron.WebViewer.html#loadDocument__anchor)().

If your URL does not have a proper file extension, then you can do the following.
myWebViewer.loadDocument("mydomain/generic_url_to_image", {filename: "input.png"})

This works with both PDFNetJS Lean and Full editions.

**TIFF, GIF, BMP**

You can utilize the browser's HTML5 canvas to load the images, and then generate PNG/JPG from the HTML5 canvas, and then pass the follow the instructions above.

**JP2 or multiple images in one document.**

Using PDFNetJS Full edition, which does not come with the standard WebViewer download, you have full control over PDF creation.
PDFNetJS Full Download: http://pdftron.com/downloads/PDFNetJS.zip

Using PDFNetJS Full you would follow the AddImage sample code to construct a PDF with the image(s) in it.
http://pdftron.com/webviewer/pdfnetjs/config.html#file=samples/PDFNet/AddImageTest/AddImageTest.js

Comment: i tried to use this method but it gives error signature is wrong below the code for js function.                                             
 https://jsfiddle.net/3v94uc9b/

Comment: The doctype variable should stay as PDF, regardless of the image type. So for example, initialDoc="mydomain.com/myfile.png" and docType="pdf"

Comment: I would be glad to help, but to follow StackOverflow guidelines, please create a new question.